# Display multiple columns from Database in ListView Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm trying to display 2 columns from database side by side in a listview  on windows form. When I use this it doesn't display pic.AddedBy. It does only Display pic.FileName
How should I do to get both columns to display side by side . I have already Created those ColumnHeaders in my ListView.
Here is my code and yhank you in advance!

```
List<Photos> list;
list = db.Photos.Where(x => x.RegNr == rgNr).ToList();
                    if (list != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Photos pic in list)
                        {
                            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(pic.FileName, pic.AddedBy); 

                            listView.Items.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listView.View should be set to Details, create two columns in designer and modify your code to:

```
foreach (Photos pic in list)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(pic.FileName); 
    item.SubItems.Add(pic.AddedBy)
    listView.Items.Add(item);
}
```